# What is the best way in unity to draw 3D objects which are lines (axis, grids, wired surfaces)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to make a 3d graph in unity and on that graph draw curves and surfaces etc. on surfaces I may have the grid texture applied on them, all of this is achievable. but there is one thing effect which I do not know how to achieve.

Many components in this app will be lines, Like the x-axis, y-axis, z-axis, & some grid on the surface, now I want these lines to have constant thickness, I may zoom into or zoom out of stuff but these lines should always be of constant thickness on the screen, a 1px line
should always be 1 pixel no matter I zoom close to it or I zoom away from it.

How can we do it? Is it an Image effect or a Shader or some other trick, I need to know what is the right approach for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that for editor usage you can use UnityEditor.Handles but you would need Renderers (feg. LineRenderer) to draw it in build